# Deploying a Dash app for many concurrent users - dcc.Store() & States

Tags: python-3.x, deployment, plotly-dash

I had a short question related to deploying a plotly Dash app via uwsgi. The app is intended to be used by many concurrent users, and we were wondering whether the current approach is suitable for many concurrent users, mainly as we're using States and a dcc.Store() component. I was unaware that using State-parameters could potentially lead to issues for many concurrent users, so any additional insight would be appreciated! If necessary, I can provide a minimal working Dash example as well.

- We designed a multi-page app via Tabs, where the user gives Inputs in three tabs. The output is subsequently displayed in a fourth tab, triggered by a callback.
- The app callback is triggered via a button (n-clicks), with many of the input parameters of the user being called via States.
- Storage type was defined as follows: *dcc.Store(id='session', storage_type='session')*
- All fields have the following persistence settings: *persistence=True, persistence_type = 'memory'*

The app itself works already for individual use, so the uwsgi and Apache server are configured correctly as the program works. The main concern at the moment is the concurrent users, and whether the input saved in States influence each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the info given it seems that you are storing all state on the clientside, and the server thus stays stateless as intended in Dash. Hence I would not expect that you run into any issues with concurrent users.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! That was also my gut feeling, and we did some initial testing writing out the input that is used in the calculation, and it seemed fine with concurrent testing on different browsers and devices, so it seems fine!